# Automatic system time update based on gps time to keep system clock accuracy

Tags: ntp, gps

I tried to use gpsd on ubuntu to provide the most accurate time to the system based on current GPS data and PPS signal. However, gpsd updates the time only once. Is there any possibility keep updating a system time whenever accuracy is off scale?

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release?  Which?

Comment: I think you need to configure ntpd or chrony too.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.